# Call a method in initialization without overriding base class's __init__

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I hope I make it clear in the title. I'm trying to inherit from `list`, and I want some of my own methods to be called when an instance of my class is created. However, I can't override `list.__init__` since that would make me unable to use `list`'s original methods. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `super.__init__` before / after you call your own methods:

```
class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CustomList, self).__init__(*args)
        # call your own methods here
```

Comment: Wow, great. Thank you!